# Is this problem a multi-label or multi-class multi-output classification?

Tags: classification, scikit-learn

I have a dataset whose input data include some numbers like x1, x2, ..., xn. I have n target columns each of which represents a binary vector including m elements. For example, a simple instance of a record of this dataset (say, n=3 and m=3) would be like:

```
|x1 | x2 | x3 ||    t1   |    t2   |   t3   |
|10 | 12 | 14 || [1,0,0] | [0,1,1] | [1,1,0]|
```

In particular, after reading [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html), I am a bit confused whether this problem is a multi-label or a multi-class multi-output classification problem. I am also wondering how I can use scikit-learn to solve a classification problem over this dataset.

Comment: I’m confused by how the parts fit together. Is each xi a different record, or a different feature of a single record? And why are the target ‘columns’ actually a matrix? This sounds like an XY problem - what is the context for what you’re trying to solve?

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy: (i) Each `xi` is a feature. In this example, each record includes three features `x1`, `x2`, and `x3`. (ii) Here is a simple imagination of the problem: each feature is the location of an agent. Each target column is a cluster whose content is a vector including 3 bits. Each bit associates with its corresponding agent. For example, `[1,1,0]` in `t3` means that agents 1 and 2 (located at `x1` and `x2`, respectively) belong to cluster 3. To save this scenario, I have used matrices in each column.